# Android Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value

Tags: android, android-emulator

I did

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/$USER/android_sdk_root
rm -rf /home/$USER/.android
rm -rf $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
mkdir -p $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
CMD_LINE_TOOLS_URL=https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip
CMD_LINE_TOOLS_SHA256=d71f75333d79c9c6ef5c39d3456c6c58c613de30e6a751ea0dbd433e8f8b9cbf
wget -O command_line_tools.zip $CMD_LINE_TOOLS_URL 
echo "$CMD_LINE_TOOLS_SHA256  command_line_tools.zip" | sha256sum -c - 
unzip command_line_tools.zip -d $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/bin
API_VER=30
sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "system-images;android-$API_VER;google_apis;x86" "platforms;android-$API_VER"
sdkmanager --sdk_root=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "emulator" "platform-tools"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
avdmanager --verbose create avd --force \
--name "emu1" \
--device "pixel" \
--package "system-images;android-$API_VER;google_apis;x86" \
--tag "google_apis" \
--abi "x86"
```

and then launched:

```
lz@d:~/Downloads$ ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/lz/android_sdk_root ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/.android/avd /home/lz/android_sdk_root/emulator/emulator -verbose @emu1
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.9.0 (build_id 8316981) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'emu1'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86
INFO    | argv[0]: '/home/lz/android_sdk_root/emulator/emulator'; program directory: '/home/lz/android_sdk_root/emulator'
VERBOSE |  Not a directory: /home/lz/android_sdk_root/android_sdk_root/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/lz/android_sdk_root]!
```

Take a look at the error

```
VERBOSE |  Not a directory: /home/lz/android_sdk_root/android_sdk_root/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
```

Why it's trying `/home/lz/android_sdk_root/android_sdk_root/`? It should be `/home/lz/android_sdk_root/`